# unzip file in android using phonegap

Tags: cordova

I want to unzip a file in android using phonegap. I am using [zip plugin](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/zip) for unzipping files.
Here is my code sample

```
zip.unzip('my_www/part4_Part_IV1.zip', 'my_www', function(d) {
   alert(d); //in alert it is showing -1
});
```

"part4_Part_IV1.zip" This file is located at my internal storage in "my_www" folder. 
I think there is a path issue and plugin is not able to locate my file so it is not extracting the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are using wrong path. For unzip plugin use below path.

```
/sdcard/my_www/config.zip
```

So your code will be like this.

```
zip.unzip('/sdcard/my_www/config.zip', '/sdcard/', function(d) {
   alert(d); 
});
```